# jQuery DateTimePicker Plugin - change header text accordingly

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using JQuery DateTimePicker plugin in my VueJs application. I have used two dateTimePickers for 'from date' and for 'to date'.

I need to change the header text of the picker to 'Select from date' when user selects From Date, and 'Select to date' when user selects To Date.

I know I can use `titleContentDate` to change the text for one. But how can I give the condition inside the function?

I have tried using it as below. But it doesn't work.

```
var self = this;
var show_txt = '';
$("#dtBox").DateTimePicker({
    beforeHide: function (oInputElement) {
        var inputName = $(oInputElement).attr('id');
        if (inputName == 'toYear') {
            show_txt = 'Select to date'
            self.form.toYear = $(oInputElement).val();
            self.form.vRequired('toYear', $(oInputElement).val())
        } else if (inputName == 'fromYear') {
            show_txt = 'Select from date'
            self.form.fromYear = $(oInputElement).val();
            self.form.vRequired('fromYear', $(oInputElement).val())
        }
    },
    titleContentDate: show_txt,
})
```

If anyone can give a solution for this, it will be a big help for me.

**EDIT:**

My datetimepicker looks like the below screenshot and I need to change the 'Set Date' accordingly.

[image]

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dtBox").DateTimePicker({  
     minDate:new Date(),
     beforeShow: function (oInputElement) {
        var inputName = $(oInputElement).attr('id');
        var titleCal = $("#"+inputName).data("namecal"); // data-namecal (titleContentDate )
        var inputNameTime = $(oInputElement).attr('id');
        var titleTim = $("#"+inputNameTime).data("nametime"); // data-nametime (titleContentTime)  
        var oDTP = this;
        oDTP.settings.titleContentDate = titleCal;
        oDTP.settings.titleContentTime = titleTim;
    }
  });
```